# Given two sets having the same cardinality what can we say about the cardinality when they are subtracted from another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $B$ and $C$ be two subsets of $A$ having the same cardinality and cardinality of $A$ is strictly greater than that of the sets $B$ and $C$ then can I conclude that $A \setminus B$ and $A\setminus C$ they both have the same cardinalities?

I constructed this question myself and have found no counterexample but I am also unable to prove it. Any help will the truly appreciated.

Comment: Are you only looking at finite cardinalities? If yes, you can use the fact that if $B \subset A$ and $|A|<\infty$, then $|A \setminus B|=|A|-|B|$. If you are considering infinite cardinalities, then this is false.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for infinite cardinalities. Can you provide one counterexample to prove it false?

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise the cardinality of $A$ is strictly greater than that of the sets $B$ and $C$. Not sure it is false anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, normal integer arithmetic proves this in the finite case. In the infinite case, we can use choice and the assumption that $A$ has strictly larger cardinality than $B$ or $C$ to prove it. This assumption on $A$ is critical, lest $A = B = \mathbb Z$ and $C = 2 \mathbb Z$ be a counterexample.

The application of choice here is that for two infinite cardinals $\lambda, \kappa$ we have $\lambda + \kappa = \max(\lambda, \kappa)$. We have $|A| = |A - B| + |B| = \max(|A - B|, |B|)$. As we assume $|B| < |A|$ we must therefore have $|A - B| = |A|$. Similarly, $|A - C| = |A|$, so $|A - B| = |A - C|$. We didn't even need the assumption that $|B| = |C|$.

Comment: I did not get this part, "The application of choice here is that for two infinite cardinals , we have +=max(,)." How do I prove that?

Comment: @Sayantan An equivalent way to say that is that for any $\kappa \leq \lambda$, $\kappa + \lambda = \lambda$. We certainly have $\lambda \leq \kappa + \lambda$. Furthermore, $\kappa + \lambda \leq \lambda + \lambda$. Do you know how to prove $\lambda + \lambda \leq \lambda$ for infinite cardinals? How do you do it for $\aleph_0$? I believe the proof should generalize using a well ordering on $\lambda$. I think transfinite induction on $\kappa$ could also work.